# Import / Export files into a SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have one document library (Not sharepoint library) on **F:\PersonalWork**

I have several folder like WorkDoc, ProposalDoc, etc, which contains .doc , .xls, .pdf, .bmp, .jpeg  etc files.

Now **F:\PersonalWork**, I have to display it as SharePoint Library with physical files in same hierarchy as I have stored in **F:\PersonalWork**

If anyone add/update/delete any file(s) in **F:\PersonalWork** folder then my sharepoint library must be reflected this changes.

Can anyone guide me how can I import a file system folder (And all files and subfolders) into a SharePoint Document Library, and also export a SharePoint Document Library to the file system

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I was recently asked a similar question.

Sharepoint does not have a mechanic for syncing files mostly because files in Sharepoint are stored in the database as blobs (binary large objects) while files on the filesystem are not (obviously).

The best way to do this would be to literally write a synchronization system where at some frequency (daily? hourly?) a SharePoint timer job checks the content of both locations and pulls / pushes files to the place they need to be, of course checking last modified DateTimes (you can manually set last modified on Windows filesystem to make it match what SharePoint gives the file).

The system would also create new folders and delete ones that no longer exist.

The hardest part of a synchronization system that goes two ways, is you either have to treat one system as the master or create a way to decide which action you actually wanted to do. By that I mean e.g. if you create a folder in Windows and then it gets synced. Then in SharePoint you delete the folder, do you recreate it? or do you delete it in Windows.

Things worth a lot of thinking.

But. I do not think it would be hard to implement, just calculate the delta on both sides and move / replace files.